# Saving a local database of .NET MAUI app issue

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, maui

I have a CRUD application using a local database (SQLite). My problem regarding saving this database is as follows:

**When I use the following code:**

```
string dbPath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, "Student.db3");
_dbConnection = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);
```

works fine when testing the app on a windows machine and I have found the file here:

```
C:\Users\{myUsername}\AppData\Local\Packages\7BD31CA9-CFFD-4A21-9B24-A87481C6221D_9zz4h110yvjzm\LocalState
```

But when running this app on the android emulator, I have no idea where it is saved... I have searched the AppData directory back and forth and used the searching functionality of the directory, but nothing.

From anyone's experience, how can I save this database file in the current directory of the project itself to ease things up?

**Notes:**

I have tried using this path, to save the file in the current directory, but nothing when testing on the Android emulator.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

It just seems to me that, the file is saved to a completely different when tested on the Android emulator but don't know where. Thoughts?

Is there any way to have the local database on the desktop machine, in the project's directory? Knowing that the database is in the android file system.

Comment: The file is created in the android file system.  You have to use adb if you want to access it from the desktop

Comment: If you log/print the value of dbPath, it will tell you where it’s stored.

Comment: @Jason I have never used that, I am pretty new to app development, how and where can I use this adb?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb

Comment: Running emulator that is different context and you can not have db on desktop. In case of Android ```FileSystem.AppDataDirectory``` returns path like: ```/data/user/0/<ApplicationID>/files```

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation:

> Returns the FilesDir of the current context, which are backed up using Auto Backup starting on API 23 and above.

Depending on how you deploy the app to the emulator, it should be in the same directory as binaries for the app.

See [File system helpers - Platform differences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/file-system-helpers?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=android#platform-differences)

Comment: Searched the binaries, not there. I think @Jason's comment is valid.